# Error installing MySQL Server via community edition installer

Tags: mysql

I recently installed MySQL Workbench and am having a plethora of problems installing MySQL Server, specifically at the "Initialize database" step where I get this error: 
https://pastebin.com/EeY99bi6

```
Beginning configuration step: Updating server
 Attempting to run mysql_upgrade.exe
Starting process for MySQL Server 5.7.22...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --console...
Process for mysqld, with ID 6976, has been started successfully and is running.
Successfully started process for MySQL Server 5.7.22.
mysqld: Character set '0.0' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\charsets\Index.xml' file
2018-07-19T20:01:03.476825Z 0 [Warning] option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192
2018-07-19T20:01:03.476910Z 0 [Warning] option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2018-07-19T20:01:03.476971Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-07-19T20:01:03.476987Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-07-19T20:01:03.479525Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.22-log) starting as process 6976 ...
2018-07-19T20:01:03.481075Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2018-07-19T20:01:03.481217Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-07-19T20:01:03.481388Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql_upgrade.exe --force --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root --password=password --verbose...
mysql_upgrade: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
Process for mysql_upgrade, with ID 8224, was run successfully and exited with code 11.
Process for MySQL Server 5.7.22 is not running.
The mysql_upgrade.exe attempt failed.  Please examine the log file for more details.
Ended configuration step: Updating server

Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
Attempting to start service MySQL58...
Failed to start service MySQL58.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 5.7.22 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
  Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:1433 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 4: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:1433 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 5: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 6: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:1433 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 7: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 8: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:1433 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 9: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:1433 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Failed to connect to MySQL Server 5.7.22 after 10 attempts.
Ended configuration step: Starting Server
```

I've tried different ports and have no idea what's going on. Anybody have any idea? Would really appreciate it - thanks.

Comment: SQL Server (Microsoft) is totally diferent from MySQL

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is pure admin issue. You may get more help at the dba site.